# Finding value in dataframe using group_by and column condition

Tags: r, group-by

I'm trying to get a date from a dataframe using the `group_by` statement, but i don't know how can it be done in R.

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
 A   B           C          D  E
 1  XX  9999-12-31 2005-11-01  0
 2  XX  2003-10-31 2002-01-01  3
 2  XX  2002-12-31 2001-03-01  3
 2  XX  2001-02-28 1998-07-11  0
 2  XX  1998-07-10 1993-04-01  3
 3  XX  .....................  3
 3  XX  .....................  3
 3  XX  2003_12-31 2003-01-01  3
 4  XX  .....
```

I would like to select the value on "D" column directly above the 0 in "E" column fro each ID in "A" column, If there's only a Zero, it doesn't matter if i keep the result or not. in this case i would like to have:

```
  A   B   C                   D  E
  1   XX  9999-12-31 2005-11-01  0  <-- Doesn't actually matters if it stays or not
  2   XX  2002-12-31 2001-03-01  3
  3   XX  2003_12-31 2003-01-01  3
  4   XX  .....
```

The dates are in order, but i can't find a way to set the value or at least remove the rows below the first zero encountered (That assuming that there could be several zeros, but it's not relevant, since the dates are in order) Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens If you don't have any `0`? Do not return that group?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot, you should just return the last value found.

Comment: @aaronparrilla Just to be clear. If there is no `0` you want date against last row for that ID ?

Comment: Yeah, just updated the question so you can check

Comment: Can a group have many rows where E = 0?

Comment: Yeah but you should stop at the first one, in case they are one after another i'm not certain about which to take, but based on the nature of the problem (initial data collection) i would assume the minimun one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ddply()` from `plyr` package in R.

```
ddply(.data = df,.variables = "A",function(dt){
    zeroind=which(dt$E==0)
    if(length(zeroind)>0){
        if(zeroind[1]>1){
            dt[(zeroind[1]-1),]
        }else{
            dt[zeroind[1],]
        }
    }else{
        dt[nrow(dt),]
    }
})
```

Comment: This only seems to return the first value of the group, can you explain what you wanted to do?

Comment: @aaronparrilla This will return the row above the row where 0 is encountered for an ID. If more than 1 zero is encountered for an ID it will return the row above the row where first zero was encountered. In case no 0 are found for an ID in column E it will return the last row for that ID. Could you please explain how does this give an output different from your expectation?

Comment: I ran the code on the real dataframe and it returns (If we use the example above) for the Zero cases it's correct but for the ID number 2 instead of returning `2001-03-01` it returns `2002-01-01`

Comment: @aaronparrilla Didn't you want the row above `0` ? Hence, this line in the code: `dt[(zeroind[1]-1),]` .